# docker-compose stop / start my_image

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Is it normal to lose all data, installed applications and created folders inside a container when executing `docker-compose stop my_image` and `docker-compose start my_image`?

I'm creating container with `docker-compose up --scale my_image=4`

**update no. 1**

my containers have sshd server running in them. When I connect to a container execute `touch test.txt` I see that the file was created.
However, after executing `docker-compose stop my_image` and `docker-compose start my_image` a container is empty and `ls -l` shows absence of file test.txt

**update no. 2**

my Dockerfile

```
FROM oraclelinux:8.5

RUN (yum update -y; \
    yum install -y openssh-server openssh-clients initscripts wget passwd tar crontabs unzip; \
    yum clean all)

RUN (ssh-keygen -A; \
     sed -i 's/UsePAM yes/#UsePAM yes/g' /etc/ssh/sshd_config; \
     sed -i 's/#UsePAM no/UsePAM no/g' /etc/ssh/sshd_config; \
     sed -i 's/#PermitRootLogin yes/PermitRootLogin yes/' /etc/ssh/sshd_config; \
     sed -i 's/#PasswordAuthentication yes/PasswordAuthentication yes/' /etc/ssh/sshd_config)

RUN (mkdir -p /root/.ssh/; \
     echo "StrictHostKeyChecking=no" > /root/.ssh/config; \
     echo "UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null" >> /root/.ssh/config)

RUN echo "root:oraclelinux" | chpasswd

COPY entrypoint.sh /entrypoint.sh
RUN chmod +x /entrypoint.sh

ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint.sh"]

EXPOSE 22
```

my docker-compose

```
version: '3.9'
services:
  my_image:
    build: 
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
    - 30000-30007:22
```

when I connect to a container

1. Execute `touch test.txt`
2. Execute `docker-compose stop my_image`
3. Execute `docker-compose start my_image`
4. Execute `ls -l`
5. I see no file `test.txt` (in fact I see that the folder is empty)

**update no. 3**

entrypoint.sh

```
#!/bin/sh

# Start the ssh server
/usr/sbin/sshd -D

# Execute the CMD
exec "$@"
```

**Other details**

When containers are all up and running, I choose a container running
on a specific port, say `port 30001`,  then using `putty` I connect to that specific container,

execute `touch test.txt`

execute `ls -l`

I do see that the file was created

I execute `docker-compose stop my_image`

I execute `docker-compose start my_image`

I connect via putty to `port 30001`

I execute `ls -l`

I see no file (folder is empty)

I try other containers to see if file exists inside one of them, but

I see no file present.

Comment: It should not do that, since it doesn't recreate container `Starts existing containers for a service.`  https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/compose_start/

Comment: Are you manually installing applications in a `docker-compose exec` debugging shell?  Regardless of the specific semantics of `docker-compose start`, it is extremely normal for this approach to lose work; you should install applications in a Dockerfile for a custom image, try to store data outside the container if possible (_e.g._, in a database), and if you can't, store data only in mounted `volumes:` directories (do not overwrite the application code using this).

Comment: That having been said, can you edit the question to include a [mcve]; what's in your image's Dockerfile, what's in the `docker-compose.yml`, what is the main container process, and how can you tell things are getting lost?

Comment: When you start the container up again, the entrypoint script is run again. What does your entrypoint script do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after a brutal brute force debugging I realized that I lose data
only when I fail to disconnect from ssh before stopping / restarting
container. When I do disconnect data does not disappear after stopping / restarting